# How many colors with their name present in the image?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am looking for a way to find the number and name of certain colors present in the image so that I can use them to count for each pixel. I am doing it but actually some other colors or can say mixed colors are also present in the image which when I count are left in the counting and it counts less and as I increase the size of image pixels the uncounted number increase. I am giving the color ranges for the visible 13 colors in the image but their are some other colors present too which I am missing. How can I find them? Thanks in advance [image]e for the help, I am stuck with the problem since long time. My image is

Comment: There are 13791 unique colours in the image (including white) which you can get by doing: `Length[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]]]`. They don't always have names. Your question is a bit vague and I'm not sure whether you want to discard other colours, count only the 13 dominant colours, or something else. You can get the 13 dominant colours excluding white like so: `domc = DominantColors[img, 13 + 1]//Rest;` If you want the colour names, there is a nice resource function here: [`NearestColorName`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NearestColorName)

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I have a question that how can I get the refined image that only contains my thirteen dominant colors including white also  from the above image of dim 1000 x 1000

Answer (score 1):

Starting point:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmMA6.png"];

dclist = DominantColors[img];

cols = Select[CommonName[WolframLanguageData[
        EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol",
        "FunctionalityAreas" -> ContainsAll[{"ColorSymbols"}]]]],
              ColorQ[ToExpression[#]] &];

nF = Nearest[ToExpression[#] -> # & /@ cols, DistanceFunction -> ColorDistance];

Thread[dclist -> Flatten[nF /@ dclist]]
(* {RGBColor[0.999777, 0.999802, 0.999843, 1.] -> "White",
    RGBColor[0.294036, 0.000946, 0.505736, 1.] -> "Purple", 
    RGBColor[0.998994, 0.747725, 0.790496, 1.] -> "LightRed", 
    RGBColor[1., 0.542326, 0.001075, 1.] -> "Orange", 
    RGBColor[0.999675, 0.999639, 0.005823, 1.] -> "Yellow", 
    RGBColor[0.00686, 0.999793, 0.999577, 1.] -> "Cyan", 
    RGBColor[0.642197, 0.16287, 0.162788, 1.] -> "Pink", 
    RGBColor[0.001085, 0.501557, 0.000758, 1.] -> "Green", 
    RGBColor[1., 0.003463, 0.00196, 1.] -> "Red",
    RGBColor[0.00411, 0.497326, 0.496575, 1.] -> "Gray", 
    RGBColor[0.044676, 0.998876, 0.033376, 1.] -> "Green", 
    RGBColor[0.999746, 0.006697, 0.999446, 1.] -> "Magenta", 
    RGBColor[0.000869, 0.000804, 0.999725, 1.] -> "Blue"} *)
```

Comment: There's also `ColorData` if you want more names, for instance: `Association[ColorData["HTML", "ColorRules"]]`